# Rationals cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, eclipse

Running Eclipse, I am working on program to do fraction addition for class, so it will probably look very unprofessional, but here goes. Basically my rational names cannot be resolved, and I'm not certain why. Does it have something to do with the scope? I've commented where the error occurs.

```
  package lab11tests;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Tests {

    private static int num1 = 0;
    private static int den1 = 1;
    private static int num2 = 0;
    private static int den2 = 1;

        static Rational r1 = new Rational(num1,den1);
         static Rational r2 = new Rational(num2,den2);
         static Rational r3 = new Rational();



        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Numerator 1: ");
            num1=input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Denominator 1: ");
            den1=input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Numerator 2: ");
            num2 = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Denominator 2: ");
            den2 = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println(r1.rational() + " + " + r2.rational() + " equals "+ r3.answer());
        }
    }
        class Rational {

        //  private int firstNum;
        //  private int firstDen;
            private int num;
            private int den;


            public Rational(int n, int d){

                num = n;
                den = d;

            }

            public Rational(){}

            public int getNum(){
                return num;
            }

            public int getDen(){
                return den;
            }

            public void add(){
                int commonDen = r1.getDen() * r2.getDen();`enter code here`
                this.num=(r1.getNum()*r2.getDen())+(r2.getNum()*r1.getDen()); //Errors are here, all r2 and r1's in the add method "cannot be resolved"
                this.den=commonDen;
            }



            public String rational(){
                return num + "/" + den;
            }

            public String answer(){
                return this.num + "/" + this.den;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Hint: To what class do variables `r1`, `r2`, `r3` belong?

Comment: The tests class I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

The code that is bugging up is inside of class Rational. Attempting to use static variables r1 and r2 will result in an error because **there is no r1 and r2 inside of class Rational**. Instead, you need to **access class Tests** to use the static variables.

This is your current code.

```java
int commonDen = r1.getDen() * r2.getDen();

this.num=(r1.getNum()*r2.getDen())+(r2.getNum()*r1.getDen()); //Errors are here, all r2 and r1's in the add method "cannot be resolved"
```

Instead, your code should look like this.

```java
int commonDen = Tests.r1.getDen() * Tests.r2.getDen();

this.num = (Tests.r1.getNum() * Tests.r2.getDen()) + (Tests.r2.getNum() * Tests.r1.getDen());
```

Answer (score 0):

Rational is a separate class here the Tests class brackets have been ended before the line of defining Rational class